# angularjs filter in the controller where value isn't empty

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, filter

I have a JSON object array, and I'm trying to filter the list down to only the objects where a value exists for a specific field.

The field I want to filter by can contain pretty much anything so theres nothing I can really look for to match against other than where a value exists.

I need to apply the filter in the angularjs controller.

The below works if I do a match gaainst a specific value like 'bob', but not all objects will have a value for "newName".

```
$scope.CorrectedNames = $filter('filter')($scope.dataList, { newName: 'bob' }).length;
console.log('Total Names to Update: '+$scope.totalCorrectedAccountNumbers.length);
```

I've tried

```
newName: '!'
```

this returns zero results.

```
newName: '!""'
```

this returns the entire json list

and they're my only 2 ideas I've come up with from searching.

The field value are blank and not NULL, otherwise I think the following would work.

```
newName: '!=null'
```

Comment: What about using js filter rather than $filter?  Like $scope.CorrectedNames = $scope.dataList.filter(x => x.newName === '');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you don't want to show objects with newName property value either null or nullstring. You should make use of pure js .filter method as follows:

```
$scope.CorrectedNames = $scope.dataList.filter(function(a) {
    if(a.newName) {
    return a.newName.trim().length !== 0;
    }
});
```

By doing this in $scope.CorrectedNames array you'll get all the objects from dataList **excluding** newName with null or nullstring or objects with no newName property.

**[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/LIq9ZiLk4LZphuQHErku?p=preview)**

Another way is you can create custom filter & inside its implementation you can do same above .filter()  method usage for filtering.